# How to delete multiple entities/objects in Room persistance

Tags: android, android-room, swipe

I use a swipe to delete my object's that are inside my RecyclerView. So if I swipe to the right I delete it first out of my RecyclerView after the swipe the user has to press my trashcan to completely delete it (also from database). It's all working fine if i delete only 1, but if i swipe more objects the all go off my screen as normal but my database just delete's the last one. I want to have it deleting all swiped objects.

I've searched for other answers but i can only find delete all or single. I think I have to hold my objects and then delete then all at once when pressing my trashcan. Just can't figure it out.

```
private void deletePerson(final oPerson person) {
     oPersonList.remove(person);
     personsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press the 
     trashcan for confirm.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     toast.show();

     //DELETE A PERSON FOREVER DATABSE
     deletePersonIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             plannerRepository.deletePerson(person);
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
             "Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             toast.show();
         }
     });
}
```

So i expect the first part to be the same, the oPersonList.remove(); is working perfect. Only the second part (after DELETE A PERSON) is going wrong. It delete's the last swiped object and needs to delete all swiped objects.

Comment: Hey, if you want to delete more than one person you have to keep all of the swiped to delete object in list, and then iterate by it and delete ach of them from database.

Comment: How do i keep all the swiped persons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to create something like this

```
    private List itemsToDelete = new ArrayList<oPerson>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    //DELETE A PERSON FOREVER DATABSE
    deletePersonIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0; i < itemsToDelete.size(); ++i){
                oPerson personToDelete = itemsToDelete.get(i);
                plannerRepository.deletePerson(personToDelete);
            }
            itemsToDelete.clear();
        }
    });
}

private void deletePerson(final oPerson person) {
    itemsToDelete.add(person)
    oPersonList.remove(person);
    personsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press the trashcan for confirm.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

As you can see, the click listener should be added only once, next we just iterate by `itemsToDelete` that store the items that was swapped out. Next the list is cleared.

Comment: Nice! I only had to change private List to private ArrayList<oPerson> but all the others worked perfectly. Thanks alot!